# actionfunction is returning null parameter value

Tags: apex, visualforce, actionfunction, custom-controller

i created a visualforce page in which actionfunction definition is

```
<apex:actionFunction name="setAttachment" action="{!setAttachment}" >
<apex:param name="attachmentBody" value=""/>
</apex:actionFunction>
```

and in my javascript code at end i am calling

```
      setAttachment(attachmentBody);
```

and setAttachment method in apex controller is

```
public void setAttachment()
{System.debug('coming here');
    String attachmentBody = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('attachmentBody');
    System.debug('attachment body is'+attachmentBody);
if(attachment == null)
System.debug('coming here');
attachment.Body = EncodingUtil.base64decode(attachmentBody);

}
```

in logs its giving attachment body is null.but i am passing a big string in javascript code function.can anyone please tell why instead of passing string its passing null as parameter in apex controller ??

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When we need to send parameter with action function then we have to use rerender attribute in  otherwise we always get null value in controller.

```
   <apex:actionFunction name="setAttachment" action="{!setAttachment}" rerender="none" >
    <apex:param name="attachmentBody" value=""/>
    </apex:actionFunction>
```

Comment: You'd think SF would have fixed this by now - I just got caught again by this...

Comment: I just got caught by this again... 2 years later. Sigh. Maybe it's me.